# Setting conditional breakpoint on all functions called by module? (WINDBG x64)

Tags: kernel, conditional-statements, windbg, breakpoints, callstack

What I would like to do is to set a conditional breakpoint on all the functions in nt called by the module I specify.

My goal with doing so is to write the callstack everytime X module calls x nt function, thereby being able to "map out" what's going on inside the obfusicated code.

After breaking on entrypoint, I set a breakpoint on x nt function. After resuming my breakpoint is hit, and the callstack looks something like

nt!function

moduleIspecified!0x123

....

My idea was then that I could use this to write a code for a conditional breakpoint, something like: "**IF caller is x module, and module is calling function inside y module THEN log callstack.**".

It's worth noting that watch and trace is not supported in x64 kernel-mode.
Its also worth mentioning that I decided this approach that I'm using this approach, because I wasn't able to determine the calls by staticly analysing it, and analysing it by stepping isnt possible either.

And also: **would there be a better/ideal approach to achieve this?**

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that precisely, but there are a few alternatives you might consider.

First of all - why not simply use [Sysinternals' Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) or perhaps [Rohitab's API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor)?

If you're bent on doing it on your own, the first problems you face is that there's small limit on the number of breakpoints the kernel debugger can set (32 is the last number I remember). This limitation isn't due to the host, WinDbg/kd, but rather du to the kernel debugger component in the target computer. You can see this in the WRK. But even if you could, it would be tremendously slow.

The first alternative you have is to but a breakpoint in the `syscall`/`sysenter` routine (`nt!KiFastCallEntry`, `nt!KisystemCall64`, or whatever it is today), and there put your commands. As I said, it's going to be **extremely** slow. You're welcome to try it yourself if you don't believe me (even without the clever condition, just put any command there, even just a simple `gc`, not to speak of `.echo`...).

The second alternative I can think of is writing a driver that hooks the system calls you're interested in (or the `syscall` routine). This saves you the roundtrip between the host and target machines. Note that you still need to attach a debugger to do disable KPP (PatchGuard) or use a 32-bit machine. And it's probably more complicated than using ProcMon, API Monitor or perhaps xperf/WPT.

I'd suggest using the easy and obvious things (ProcMon/API Monitor) before going for the overly complicated ones.